# Can I write multiple Assembly instructions on the same line?

Tags: assembly

Can I write multiple Assembly instructions on the same line the same way I can do with most high level languages. Or does each Assembler treats this feature differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Each assembler has its own syntax**. Even Intel syntax on x86 is actually not the same across different assemblers. Some examples

- [Does FASM uses Intel Syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27682380/995714)
- [MASM/NASM Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035747/995714)
- [ASM: MASM, NASM, FASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10179933/995714)
- [Difference between FASM and MASM/TASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593798/995714)
- [How to know if an assembly code has particular syntax (emu8086, NASM, TASM, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853636/995714)

Most assemblers accept **newline** as the instruction separator but some assemblers may also define another separation character so that you don't have to write each instruction on its own line. [GAS](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_node/as_30.html) listed `@` and `$` as the other statement-ending characters but I'm not sure if they allow multiple instructions to be separated by those characters. It also supports separating instructions with `;` so you can write those in one line like `inc eax; int 3`

> A statement ends at a newline character (`'\n'`) or an "at" sign (`'@'`). [...] A statement ends at a newline character (`'\n'`) or an exclamation point (`'!'`).  [...] A statement ends at a newline character (`'\n'`); or (for the H8/300) a dollar sign (`'$'`); or (for the Hitachi-SH or the H8/500) a semicolon (`';'`).  [...] A statement ends at a newline character (`'\n'`) or line separator character. (**The line separator is usually `';'`, unless this conflicts with the comment character; see section Machine Dependent Features.**)

MASM doesn't support multiple instructions on the same line but you can create a VARARG macro to achieve similar effect

```
_ macro args:VARARG
   asm_txt TEXTEQU <>
   FORC char,<&args>
      IFDIF <&char>,<!\>
         STR asm_txt,<&char>
      ELSE
         asm_txt
         asm_txt TEXTEQU <>
      ENDIF
   ENDM
   asm_txt
endm
```

Then use it like this `_ mov eax, -1 \ mov ebx, 2`. More information here: [Multiple instructions on one line?](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=786dd40408172108b65a5a36b09c88c0&topic=16931;prev_next=next)

---

For **inline assembly**, particularly in gcc, as newline ends the previous instruction, you can get instructions to work in one single line by emitting `'\n'` between them

```c
// unsafe: clobbers the red-zone in the x86-64 System V calling convention.
asm("push rax\n\t" "mov rax, 0\n\t" "pop rax");
```

or you can use multiple asm statements (edit: **not recommended** as Peter Cordes said in the comment)

```c
// unsafe: compiler can put its own code between these, or maybe even reorder them
// and without operands + clobbers, you can't mess with the compiler's registers.
asm("mov rbx, rax"); asm("xor rdx, rbx"); asm("mov rcx, 5");
```

However, because `gas` and `as` support the use of `;` to separate instructions as mentioned above, [you can also use it in gcc like `__asm__("xor eax, eax; inc eax")`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43053197/995714) because

> The compiler copies the assembler instructions in a basic asm verbatim to the assembly language output file...
>
> ## AssemblerInstructions
>
> This is a literal string that specifies the assembler code. The string can contain any instructions recognized by the assembler, including directives. GCC does not parse the assembler instructions themselves and does not know what they mean or even whether they are valid assembler input.
>
> **You may place multiple assembler instructions together in a single asm string, separated by the characters normally used in assembly code for the system**. A combination that works in most places is a newline to break the line, plus a tab character (written as `\n\t`). **Some assemblers allow semicolons as a line separator**. However, note that some assembler dialects use semicolons to start a comment.
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Basic-Asm.html

MSVC also has `;` as instruction separator, because its syntax is

```
__asm assembly-instruction [ ; ]
__asm { assembly-instruction-list } [ ; ]
```

However, [you can even used the keyword `__asm` itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx) to separate instructions

> Because the __asm keyword is a statement separator, you can also put assembly instructions on the same line:
>
> ```
> __asm mov al, 2   __asm mov dx, 0xD007   __asm out dx, al
> ```

[ARM RealView Assembler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_cihccdja.htm) also supports `;` as an instruction separator like:

> When compiling C++, the ARM compiler supports the `asm` syntax proposed in the ISO C++ Standard. You can specify inline assembler code using the following formats:
>
> - On a single line, for example:
>
>   `asm("instruction[;instruction]"); // Must be a single string`
>     `asm{instruction[;instruction]}`
>     ...
> - If you include multiple instructions on the same line, you must separate them with a semicolon (;). If you use double quotes, you must enclose all the instructions within a single set of double quotes (").

Comment: Gah, no you can't use multiple asm statements.  The compiler is free to put anything it wants between separate `asm` statements, potentially clobbering registers.  Please don't recommend that people do this.  GNU C + GAS for x86 does support `asm("mov rbx, rax;"` `"xor rdx, rbx;"` `"mov rcx, 5");` instead of `\n\t`, but `\n\t` looks better when you look at `gcc -S` output (separate lines instead of one long line).

Comment: The comment character for GAS on ARM is `@`.

Comment: `asm("push rax\n\t" "mov rax, 0\n\t" "pop rax");` clobbers the red-zone; it's not safe either.  Here's an example of breakage:
 [Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34520013).  I guess it's not a bad idea to mention wrong ways of using inline asm just to point them out to beginners who could easily think of them on their own.  But it would be better to have a comment right in the code block where people will see it even if skimming, which says *what* about it is unsafe.

Comment: Another quirky variation: [How do we write multiple statements on one line in AArch64 assembly for Apple platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66775472) - Apparently MacOS `as` / `clang` for AArch64 uses `%%` as a separator, with `;` as a comment character.  (But *only* when targeting Mac platforms; on Linux `clang target aarch64 -c foo.s` still uses `;` as a separator.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. It's up to the assembler to allow it or not. The best way to find out about the syntax details, I think, is to look into the assembler's documentation.

Comment: GAS uses `;` as a separator for instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the input. But as I see it, the semicolon is not guaranteed to be a line separator in all scenarios. For example, current *gas* manual says "The presence of a ‘;’ anywhere on a line indicates the start of a comment that extends to the end of that line. " under section 9.5 "AVR Dependent Features" (Subsection: "Special Characters").

Comment: Neat, I wondered if `;` was the comment character for any architectures GAS supported.  Removed my downvote now that you removed the wrong part of this answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes from gas manual: [The line separator is usually ';', unless this conflicts with the comment character; see section Machine Dependent Features](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_node/as_30.html)

Comment: Semicolon works on LLVM's builtin GAS compatible assembler.