# How to write multiple assembly statements within asm() without "\t\n" separating each line using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

> How to write multiple assembly statements within asm() without "\t\n" separating each line using GCC?

I've seen some textbooks write multiple assembly statements within `asm()` as:

```
asm("
movl $4, %eax
movl $2, %ebx
addl %eax, %ebx
...
");
```

However, my compiler (GCC) doesn't recognize this syntax. Instead, I must rely on `"\t\n"` separating each line or using multiple `asm()`:

```
asm(
"movl $4, %eax\t\n"
"movl $2, %ebx\t\n"
"addl %eax, %ebx\t\n"
...);
```

or

```
asm("movl $4, %eax");
asm("movl $2, %ebx");
asm("addl %eax, %ebx");
...
```

How do I enable the "clean" syntax with no `"\t\n"` or repeated `asm()`?

Comment: And what is your problem? The syntax is "clean" with the linebreaks. Not sure why you use the tabs. Inline-assembly should be used sparesly and only for short snippets anyway **if unavoidable**.

Comment: I would argue that the correct solution is to *not* use inline assembly to begin with. :)

Comment: @Olaf - I don't want to repeatedly write "\n"?

Comment: The solution is simple: use a seperate assembly file.

Comment: Don't write long code inline, thus you won't have to type many `\n` ;)

Comment: @Olaf - and then link and call the functions defined in this file?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the inline asm block supports raw string literals, but give it a try.

Comment: Why don't you just write clear, maintainable C++ instead and let the compiler worry about the asm?  Unless you are doing something *really* low level or optimizing a *really* critical function (and *really* know what you are doing) the compiler is probably going to write better asm than you anyway.

Comment: imho it is a bit funny that you want to write assembler and you are worrying about a line break. I would rather worry about everything else in that block ;)

Comment: What sort of advice is 'you should never write assembler'? Jeez, hasn't anyone here ever experimented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write multiple Assembly instructions on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685548/can-i-write-multiple-assembly-instructions-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GCC

Your inline assembly is ill advised since you alter registers without informing the compiler. You should use [GCC's extended inline assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) with proper input and output constraints. Using inline assembler should be used as a [last resort](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) and you should understand exactly what you are doing. *GCC*'s inline assembly is very unforgiving, as code that seems to work may not even be correct.

With that being said ending each string with `\n\t` makes the generated assembler code look cleaner. You can see this by compiling with the `-S` parameter to generate the corresponding assembly code. You do have the option of using a `;` (semicolon). This will separate each instruction but will output all of the instructions on the same assembler line.  And yes this matters: looking at the `-S` output is a good way to see how the compiler substituted operands into your asm template and put its own code around yours.

Another option is to use *C* line continuation character `\` (backslash). Although the following will generate excessive white space in generate assembly code it will compile and assemble as expected:

```
int main()
{
    __asm__("movl $4, %eax; \
             movl $2, %ebx; \
             addl %eax, %ebx"
          ::: "eax", "ebx");
}
```

Although this is a way of doing it, I'm not suggesting that this is good form. I have a preference for the form you use in your second example using `\n\t` without line continuation characters.

---

Regarding splitting up multiple instructions into separate *ASM* statements:

```
asm("movl $4, %eax");
asm("movl $2, %ebx");     // unsafe, no operands specifying connections
asm("addl %eax, %ebx");
```

This is problematic. The compiler can reorder these relative to one another since they are basic assembler with no dependencies. It is possible for a compiler to generate this code:

```
movl $4, %eax
addl %eax, %ebx
movl $2, %ebx
```

This of course would not generate the result you expect. When you place all the instructions in a single *ASM* statement they will be generated in the order you specify.

---

### MSVC/C++

32-bit Microsoft C and C++ compilers support an extension to the language that allows you to place multi-line inline assembly between `__asm {` and `}`. Using this mechanism you don't place the inline assembly in a *C* string; don't need to use line continuation; and no need to end a statement with with a `;` (semicolon).

An example of this would be:

```
__asm {
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 2
    add ebx, eax
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael - Finally an answer that address my question.

Comment: Still I find it weird that, e.g. The Shellcoder Hacker's Handbook, use the syntax I mention first.

Comment: @Shuzheng  I only had access to the second edition of the Shellcoders handbook (online) and it is clear they have made some errors in that regard. In the second edition though they get the syntax correct in Chapter 4 page 79 in the example. In that case they use the backslash  line continuation character and ended each line with a `;` as I did in my answer, but I'm not personally fond of doing it that way.

Comment: using `asm volatile` forces the compiler to generate the code in order

Comment: `asm("")` is implicitly `volatile`; reordering isn't the problem (except with buggy compilers; lack of clobber declarations means it can't be safely used inside a non-`naked` function

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do...

```
int main()
{
    __asm__(
            "movl $4, %eax;"
            "movl $2, %ebx;"
            "addl %eax, %ebx;"
           );
}
```