# Name of C function changes?

Tags: c, symbols, elf, name-mangling

I had the following C code:

```
void test_func()
{
    __asm__ ("mov    $0x2,%rax");
    __asm__ ("mov    $0x6000dd,%rdi");
    __asm__ ("mov    $0x0,%rsi");
    __asm__ ("syscall");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test_func();
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it like this `gcc mine.cxx -S -no-pie` I get in assembly file the following:

```
.globl _Z9test_funcv
```

Why does the name of my function change and how to prevent this / predict its new name?

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: [Don't split up instructions into splitting separate `__asm__` statements like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43054507/995714). The compiler may insert instructions between them or even *"reorder these relative to one another since they are basic assembler with no dependencies"*

Comment: @phuclv like how?

Comment: @ariel did you read the link above? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27685548/995714#comment85353418_27687809). Just separate the instructions with `\n` or `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're compiling it as C++ code, not C. In C++ [names are mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to support things like [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) and templates. Mangling rules depend on compiler but it usually begins with `_Z`, especially in compilers following [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)

See [What is name mangling, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1314743/995714)

You need to compile the code as C. The compiler usually determines the language based on the extension, and in GCC [`cxx` is one of the C++ extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b) so just rename the file to `*.c`. You can also force the compiler to compile code as C regardless of the extension. The option to do that depends on compiler, for example in MSVC use [`/TC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=msvc-160) and in GCC use [`-x c`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)

Note that you should [**never put instructions in separate `__asm__` statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27685548/995714#comment85353418_27687809) like that because the compiler is allowed to put arbitrary instructions between them

Comment: Sorry you are wrong here is how I did it: gcc mine.cxx -S -no-pie

Comment: @ariel: Why did you give your file a C++ file extension if you wanted to write C?

Comment: cxx isn't C++ extension

Comment: @ariel Reading the manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b shows you that the  extension `cxx` **is** causing GCC to compiie as C++.

Comment: @ariel if you rotate `xx` 45° then it'll (roughly) become `++`. That's why `CXX` is often used in macros denoting C++ code. Same to the cxx extension