# How do we write multiple statements on one line in AArch64 assembly for Apple platforms?

Tags: assembly, arm64, apple-m1

I'm porting a bit of Arm64 assembly language to an M1.

Some of it is generated by C preprocessing, in which a single `#define` macro generates multiple statements separated by semicolon.

Unfortunately, on the M1, the assembler treats the semicolon as a comment character.

For instance:

```
#define DEFUN(NAME)  \
  .globl _ ## NAME ; \
  .palign 2 ;        \
  _ ## NAME:
```

causes everything after the `.globl` directive to be treated as a comment.

The MacOS `as` man page provides no clue; it has no coverage of syntax.

Is there an alernative character for separating statements? I tried using `@` and `!`, but both are rejected.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685548/can-i-write-multiple-assembly-instructions-on-the-same-line) are of no use here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For aarch64 assembly targeting Apple platforms, you can use `%%` as separator character. Not sure if/where it's documented, but it's set in the LLVM source [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-12.0.0-rc3/llvm/lib/Target/AArch64/MCTargetDesc/AArch64MCAsmInfo.cpp#L40). And even if it might not be documented explicitly anywhere, it is used in a number of places, e.g. in [libunwind](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-12.0.0-rc3/libunwind/src/assembly.h#L28-L30) and [compiler-rt](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-12.0.0-rc3/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/assembly.h#L17-L21), so it probably won't change in a whim.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that works perfectly. I can now throw away the annoying special case treatment of this platform.